# Como extraer el info_hash de un torrent con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un decoder para bencode y estuve rato largo tratando de obtener el info_hash de esto:

`d10:created by18:qBittorrent v4.2.513:creation datei1617086975e4:infod6:lengthi6e4:name10:asdasd.txt12:piece lengthi16384e6:pieces20:�ly���6���c�p�e��7ee`

https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification

Lei ese artículo 3 veces y aún así, no puedo entender a que se supone que le tengo que hacer un SHA1 para obtener el info_hash. Agradeceria cualquier ayuda.

Comment: In spanish, please

Comment: Estoy intentando sacar el info_hash de un torrent pero no entiendo a que parte del torrent le tengo que hacer un sha1.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y ponla en español

Comment: Tenes razon, disculpame.